# Selecting items in a list based on multiple conditions Part 2

Tags: list-manipulation

This question has been solved. Thanks for all your help!

I encounter another problem, which is related to a previous [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109038/selecting-items-in-a-list-based-on-multiple-conditions). 
Now, I have data for different days, so that my data now looks like this:

```
{{{{1,3}},{{2,3},{5,2},{2,3},{4,1}},{{4,3},{1,1},{3,2},{5,4},{7,6}},{{2,6},{3,3}}},{{{2,4}},{{3,3},{4,2},{5,3},{4,1}},{{4,3},{1,1},{4,3},{5,4}}}}
```

Again: `{}` represents the coordinates of an object at time 1, `{{ }}` represents each single object, and `{{{ }}}` represent all the movements of different objects in a day.

Similar to before, how would I delete only the objects that moved more than 2 times, and that have the same position at times 1 and 3. So, in this case, those objects would be:

```
{{2,3},{5,2},{2,3},{4,1}} in day 1 and {{4,3},{1,1},{4,3},{5,4}} in day 2
```

And I would like to keep all the other data.

I tried using 'Flatten' and then 'List'; But, that makes me lose track of what data is from what day.

I realize this might not be too hard. But, I am supposed to modify an existing code, and I am just now getting familiar to mathematica.

So, Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: you're challenging no one. This site isn't about challenging but about helping.

Comment: @Dr. belisarius  I realized that was not the best way to phrase that (sorry about that, english is not my first language). I guess, I meant that it has been a challenge for me to figure it out. I agree, the site is about helping each other, and I am very appreciate of that.

Comment: Anyway, see `Map[ ]`. You should be able to solve this one based on the answers you got for your previous question

Comment: So this, I think (using the answer from the other question): Map[DeleteCases[#, {x_, _, x_, ___}] &, list]

Comment: That worked, Thanks!!